# How to edit the PDF file using MuPDF pod which was installed by the following method mentioned by other user,

Tags: ios, mupdf

I could run the app successfully by downloading & following the steps mentioned [here](https://github.com/jogu/MuPDF-example). But i'm unable to edit the pdf file & unable to save it.

Comment: What is your question? It looks like you just copied/wrote some text.

Comment: I could run the app successfully by downloading & following the steps mentioned here(https://github.com/jogu/MuPDF-example). But i'm unable to edit the pdf file & unable to save it.